Cannot see camera to view and cannot see camera bounds
I'm having an issue with one particular 4.2 file, I cannot see camera to view by pressing zero and adjust the camera and also cannot see the camera bounds.
I have deleted multiple times the camera to see if it will fix the issue, but cannot find a solution. I will also upload the file.



Press Home button

You can't see the camera borders because you've zoomed too much, unlock the Camera to View option and zoom out. Also you have enabled the View Region mode, to exit press AltCtrlB:


Thanks for that, I dont even know how I did this camera mistake to zoom out so much.
